# Bundle savedInstanceState null when Adding a widget to a existing Xamarin Android App

Tags: android, xamarin, widget

I have and **existing** android app developed with **Xamarin**.

It works perfect.

I decided to create a widget for my app, and I followed 
[Xamarin Widget Sample](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/SimpleWidget), [http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/22941...](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/22941/how-do-i-include-in-my-app-widget) and [Vogela Widget tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidWidgets/article.html) guidelines to add what it's needed.

Unfortunately since them the app crashes on start with this exception

> Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.setId(int)' on a null object reference

The problem comes because when loading the first activity and doing `base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);` `Bundle savedInstanceState` is null.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally found the error by myself.
It seems the xml folder gives some errors on xamarin android.
I just moved the contento to layout and reference it as `layout/` instead of `/xml`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution as mentioned [here](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/issues/467#issuecomment-450729439)

> delete `bin` and `obj` folders on Android project and rebuild it